# Get console logs from firefox running on a node in selenium GRID with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, console.log

I am able to get console logs with chromedriver with `get_log()` function.

But when I try it with Firefox, it gives me some weird logs related to its extensions and add-ons.

Can somebody help me out here?